# how to say "I want to take revenge on somebody"

Tags: vocabulary

I don't leave you alone until I **take revenge on you** for these bitter days

Have I correctly written that? I am seeking for other phrases rather than the bold one.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Another option that I'm just leaving as a comment is "get even with (someone)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say:

> to take revenge (against somebody)
>
> to seek revenge (against someone)
>
> get revenge against someone
>
> take revenge (on someone) (for something)

The words between parentheses are optional and do not necessarily need to be expressed.

Also, `I don't leave you alone until...` is incorrect. Since you're using a future expression here (`until`), you need the future verb form `won't` here.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for other phrases, you can use this one:

> I won't leave you alone until I **pay you back** for these bitter days.

The [Century Dictionary](https://www.wordnik.com/words/repay) defines *repay* as:

> To make return, retribution, or requital for, in a good or bad sense: as, to repay kindness; to repay an injury.

Similarly, *pay you back* can be used for either revenge or for kindness, but it's often easy to tell from the context which meaning is intended.

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close.

> I *won't* leave until **I take my revenge upon you** for these bitter days.

another alternative would be to say `get my revenge against you`

please note it is `won't` instead of `don't` due to your use of future tense (as Vlammuh has also pointed out)S

Answer (score 0):

Other phrases you could use:

> get back at you..
>
> get even with you..
>
> make you pay for..
>
> rare: wreak vengeance on you for..